# How to refresh my div after submit comment?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am using `smarty framework` in my project, I perfectly did my comment system but I cannot get the exactly result I want.

This is my PHP code inside `event-detail.php` :

```
$event_comment = $eventComment->geteventcomment($record, $startfrom, $max);
$tpl->assign("event_comment", $event_comment);
$tpl->display("event-detail.html");
```

This is HTML code inside `event-detail.php` :

```
//this is javasctipt
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // on post comment click 
        $('.bt-add-com').click(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "add-comment.php",
                    data: 'act=add-com&event_id='+theEventId.val()+'&comment='+theCom.val()+'&user_id='+theUserId.val()+'&user_name='+theUserName.val()+'&file_path='+theFilePath.val(),
                    success: function(html){
                        theCom.val('');
                        theEventId.val('');
                        theUserId.val('');
                        theUserName.val('');
                        theFilePath.val('');
                        $('.new-com-cnt').hide('fast', function(){
                            $('.new-com-bt').show('fast');
                            $('.new-com-bt').before(html);  
                        })
                    }  
                });

        });

    });
</script>
<div class="content-container-left">
<{section name=thisrsa loop=$event_comment}>

    <div class="comment-box">
        <div class="comment-listing">
        <div><small><{$event_comment[thisrsa].date}></small></div>
            <div class="avatar">
                <img src="<{$smarty.const._CONST_CONTENT_MEMBER_THUMBNAIL}><{$event_comment[thisrsa].file_path}>"/> 
                <p><{$event_comment[thisrsa].name}></p>
            </div>
            <div class="comment-template">
                <p><{$event_comment[thisrsa].content}></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
   <{/section}>
</div>
```

This is SQL statement which I had did it limit 3 record shows each page :

```
function geteventcomment($record, $startfrom, $max){
            global $db,$comment;
            $arrResult = array();

            $stmt = "SELECT tbl1.event_id, tbl2.name, tbl2.file_path, tbl1.text, tbl1.modified_timestamp, tbl1.creation_timestamp FROM "._CONST_TBL_EVENT_COMMENT." tbl1, "._CONST_TBL_ALUMNI." tbl2 WHERE tbl1.event_id = $record AND tbl1.member_id = tbl2.id ORDER BY tbl1.creation_timestamp DESC";
            $stmt .= " LIMIT $startfrom, $max";
            if($rs = $db->Execute($stmt))
            {
                while($rsa = $rs->FetchRow())
                {
                    array_push($arrResult, array(
                        "id" => $record,
                        "name" => $rsa['name'],
                        "file_path" => $rsa['file_path'],
                        "content" => $rsa['text'],
                        "date" => $rsa['modified_timestamp']
                    ));
                }           
            }           
            return $arrResult;
        }
```

I had get the following result in my website :

[image]

But what I really want is to refresh div and make it only display the latest 3 comment in my website, like below :

[image]

I hope I can get some help from you guys.

Comment: Can't you simplify your code for yout question ?

Comment: I had simplify my code

Comment: Do you want to force the user to refresh the page, or do you want to refresh the div dynamicly?

Comment: I want it dynamic. dynamic will be more better

Answer (score 0):

Please check if following code helps.

```
$('.new-com-cnt').hide('fast', function(){
  $('.new-com-bt').show('fast');
  $('.new-com-bt').empty().append(html);  
});
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle. Just reading a code is little bit difficult.
Also is there any container div containing you images and text rows?
Can you paste your HTML output of your "<div class="content-container-left">..." PHP code

Comment: actually what I want is only need to refresh the div and only show latest 3 comment. Means that when user submit comment and his comment will be appear and after that the latest third comment will disappear.